# Progressive matrix: Matrices

Tags: mathematics, progressive-matrix

This is a progressive matrix problem that I created myself and I can confirm that there is only one unique solution. It may look complex at first, but is pretty easy when you figure out what to do.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}&&\begin{bmatrix}7&10\\15&22\end{bmatrix}&&\begin{bmatrix}37&54\\81&118\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}199&290\\435&634\end{bmatrix}&&\begin{bmatrix}1069&1558\\2337&3406\end{bmatrix}&&\begin{bmatrix}5743&8370\\12555&18298\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}30853&44966\\67449&98302\end{bmatrix}&&\begin{bmatrix}165751&241570\\362355&528106\end{bmatrix}&&\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

$$\text{Is }\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\text:\\\begin{align}a.&\quad\begin{bmatrix}890461&1297782\\1946673&2837134\end{bmatrix}\\b.&\quad\begin{bmatrix}890462&1299782\\1846673&2937134\end{bmatrix}\\c.&\quad\begin{bmatrix}1003157&136573\\1934333&3031238\end{bmatrix}\\d.&\quad\begin{bmatrix}890461&1297782\\1946673&2837135\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$<sub>Sorry for the matrices not being spaced out too well, unsure how I would make this better</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These are just consecutive powers of the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}. Therefore, the answer is $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}^9=\boxed{\mathbf a}$.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer! good job!

Comment: I'm glad tools exist to calculate matrix products—there is _no way_ I would do that by hand!

Comment: You can do $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}\\=\begin{bmatrix}ae+bg&af+bh\\ce+dg&cf+dh\end{bmatrix}$$to do 2x2 matrix multiplication

Comment: I know, but when the numbers get too big…

Comment: I know what you mean. It does suck trying to do matrix multiplication by hand really fast sometimes, even when calculating small powers of 2x2 matrices with entries that aren't even that large.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&bc+d^2\end{bmatrix}$ For future reference by anyone else reading this.

Comment: SE is making us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149824/discussion-between-someone-and-crsb0001).